# How to execute a simple Java Program through MATLAB?

Tags: java, matlab, file, class

I have written a simple java code on Notepad

```
public class Hello

{

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {

       System.out.println("Hello");

    }

}
```

I have compiled this using CMD and convert it into class file. I opened MATLAB command window and opened edit classpath.txt and put the complete path of Hello.class file and restarted MATLAB. I just want to know that now how will I execute this simple java program through MATLAB? am I doing write or wrong?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Umm, sorry for the sarcasm, but [did you google it](http://googleitfor.me/?q=How+to+execute+a+simple+Java+Program+through+MATLAB%3F&l=0)? [The first result](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99993-how-do-i-call-a-simple-hello-world-java-program-in-matlab) contains the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After you restart MATLAB, you have to create a class object and then execute it.

Create a class of HelloWorld

hw = HelloWorld

Then execute it.

javaMethod('main', hw, '')

Comment: Thanks jerr for the answer.. But when I am going through this we got an error message
??? Undefined function or variable 'Hello'.

Comment: First of all i have written the java code mentioned above and compiled to convert class file. Than i opened classpath.txt using edit classpath.txt using MATLAB and than i gave the complete path of class file C:\Users\Sanjay\Desktop\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\Hello.class and than i restarted MATLAB and I executed hw = Hello and got the error message ??? Undefined function or variable 'Hello'

Comment: That is because there is no function or variable 'Hello'. The class is HelloWorld with the World and you have to declare it that way.